# Problems with simultaneous PUT/GET with ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I'm implementing a cache-like application that uses `NavigableMap` data-structure for caching textual data (a few hundred `JSON` Strings) for 20 different usernames (right now only two- eventually would scale to around 20 usernames). I have have 7 time-series caches/`NavigableMaps` for 7 different types, for each username, refreshing every 30 mins. And then in a server thread, given a type, a time range and username, I access the corresponding `NavigableMap`.

When I had a single username, I had 7 `NavigableMap <Long, String>` separately and all perfect. But to handle more users, I created a parent static `ConcurrentHashMap`, with each key (i.e. username) mapping to its own `NavigableMap`, with each caching done in a separate thread (i.e. 20 threads). All adding up to the parent `HashMap`.

After adding another `NavigableMap` with more data than others for another type and higher retrieval rates, I ***sometimes*** some weird **retreival (get)** problems, even at times `ConcurrentHashMap` is not updated with `put`. My guess is it fails to retrieve data from the `ConcurrentHashMap`.

What is the problem? Is the single `ConcurrentHashMap` data structure cause any problems for fast retrievals? And second, **PUT** of two different keys at the same time, does it cause any problems?

Here are the main definitions:

```
public class MyCache {
        static ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> map1= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> ();
        static ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> map2= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> ();
        static ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> map3= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> ();
        static ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> map4= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> ();
        static ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> map5= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> ();
        static ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> map6= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> ();
        static ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> map7= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NavigableMap <Long, String>> ();

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Server(); //new server thread accessing caches
    for (int i =0 ; i< users.length; i++) //cache data for each username
         new Caching();
    }
}
```

Here is a sample `PUT` that can happen at the same time:

```
MyCache.map1.put(username, new ConcurrentSkipListMap <Long, String> (map1Temp));
```

And here is the accessing/`GET` part:

```
    //...
    switch (type) {
            case "type1":
                list = new ArrayList<String>(MyCache.map1.get(username).subMap(start, end).values());
                break;

            case "type2":
                list = new ArrayList<String>(MyCache.map2.get(username).subMap(start, end).values());
                break;
    // ...
            case "type7":
                list = new ArrayList<String>(MyCache.map7.get(username).subMap(start, end).values());
                break;
//and send the array as text over HTTP
```

Comment: When you create a new entry for a given username, how are you doing it? Is there a chance there is some contention around the process which "fetches or creates the NavigableMap for a username"?

Comment: I create a temporary NavigableMap with data. Then copy it quickly to the main HashMap: `MyCache.map1.put(username, new ConcurrentSkipListMap <Long, String> (map1Temp));`

Comment: It works. But I see this behaviour happening sometimes.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads doing the `put`? Because "copying it quickly" is not going to cut it :) Best to do `MyCache.map1.computeIfAbsent(username, x -> new ConcurrentSkipListMap <Long, String> (map1Temp));`. This might be the issue.

Comment: Yes 2 threads can put at the same time. But they have 2 different usernames. Is that a problem?! If that was a problem, then it just didn't have valid data. But now the problem is on `get`, not put.

Comment: btw, every time I refresh, I need to update the value/ put a fresh data. I guess `computeIfAbsent` only puts if that key didn't exists.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide some more concrete examples by way of code, to describe what is/is not happening - difficult to ascertain what's going on otherwise!

Comment: Yeah trying to simulate the error somehow. Can't find one. Just asked the question to see if anything is wrong with my data structures above.

Comment: can you at least show the minimal structure that you use and how? I've read your question 3 times, still can't tell what is going on

Comment: Any reason why `map2` suddenly has type `Map` rather than `ConcurrentHashMap`? Or why these fields are not declared `final`? And do you really think “*some weird retreival (get) problems*” is a useful problem description?

Comment: Typo. Fixed it.

Comment: You still didn’t explain, what kind of “some weird retrieval (get) problems” you have.

Comment: Actually the problem was coming from other things. It's fixed.